# Convert HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: reverse-proxy, https

I'm having an HTTPS WordPress website. On this website I have a couple of audiostreams from external HTTP sources. Is there a way to convert those external HTTP streams to HTTPS? The HTTP streams won't play because its unsafe.

Comment: You can't do that. Only whoever runs that web site can do that. Contact them first.

Comment: Since it's the OP's website, if his server were to fetch these streams and relay them, shouldn't that solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

This task can be solved by some kind of own proxy script. This script will download all http videos to your server and distribute them to the user.

Alternative way will be to manually upload them to some other hosting platform and fix urls

Comment: You could run into a copyright problem if you do this and the copyright holder notices (which eventually they will) and cares enough to do something about it.